# Update Codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

Estou tentando fazer um `UPDATE` no banco de dados usando CodeIgniter, porém o `UPDATE` não está sendo executado do jeito que eu gostaria.

O que acontece, tenho 5 manuais com conteúdos diferentes, e quando faço o `UPDATE` desta seguinte maneira ele muda o conteúdo de todos manuais juntos, sendo que quero mudar apenas o conteúdo de um determinado manual, creio que tenho que de alguma forma usar a identificação de cada um (`id`), porém já tentei diversas formas e não consegui chegar ao resultado esperado.

Abaixo segue o Código

**HTML:**

```
<form class="form-horizontal form-material" id="manual-form" method="post" action="<?php echo base_url('app/Manual/salvar'); ?>"> 
    <!--  Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade " id="myModal" style="padding-top: 0px;">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
            <div class="modal-content">

                <!-- Modal Cabecalho -->
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title"><?php echo $servico_manual->titulo; ?></h4>
                    <button type="button" class="close" style="outline:0;-webkit-box-shadow:none;box-shadow: none;" data-dismiss="modal">&times;
                    </button>
                </div>

                <!-- Modal Corpo -->
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <input id ="conteudo" name="conteudo" aria-hidden="true" style="width:100%;border-color:#cccccc;outline:0;-webkit-box-shadow:none;box-shadow: none;" value="<?php echo $servico_manual->conteudo; ?>">   
                </div>
                <!-- Modal Rodape-->
                <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn " style="background-color: #1d436f;color:white;outline:0;-webkit-box-shadow:none;box-shadow: none;" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>

                <!-- Botão abaixo para salvar edições feitas no conteudo do Manual -->
                <button type="submit" class="btn" style="background-color: #1d436f;color: white;outline:0;-webkit-box-shadow:none;box-shadow: none;">Salvar Alterações</button>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Função da Controller:**

```
public function salvar($id=null)
{
    $conteudo = $_POST["conteudo"];
    $this->Manualserv->conteudo = $conteudo;
    $this->Manualserv->atualizar_conteudo_manual($id);
    $data['page_title'] = 'Manual Servidor';
    $this->load->view('app/index', $data);
    redirect(base_url() . 'app/manual/manualservidores/', 'refresh');
}
```

**Model:**

```
public function atualizar_conteudo_manual($id_processo_manual) 
{
    $dadosmanual_update = array ("conteudo"=>$this->conteudo);
    return $this->db->update('tb_processos_manuais',$dadosmanual_update);
}
```

Comment: Opa, pode ser que o $id no controller esteja indo como null e atualizando a todos. No formulário html, tenta passar o id na action, de alguma maneira que envie a url com o id:  action="<?php echo base_url('app/Manual/salvar/48'); ?>"

Comment: Não adiantou, e mesmo assim se eu passasse o $id na action ele ficaria atualizando sempre o mesmo não?

Comment: Creio que você ta dando update na tabela, mas faz um teste .
Veja se dentro do `atualizar_conteudo_manual` você pode visualizar as informações da sua coluna baseada no seu `id`, use um var_dump ou algo assim, caso você consiga ver os valores. Use o update em cima deste dado.

Comment: Utilizando o var_dump eu consigo visualizar as informações da coluna , porém o `id` esta vindo como NULL, ai que está o problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Na verdade seu problema é bem básico, você esta fazendo update sem where, segue um exemplo para consulta:

```
$this->db->set('field', 'field+1', FALSE);
$this->db->where('id', 2);
$this->db->update('mytable'); // gives UPDATE mytable SET field = field+1 WHERE id = 2
```

Sem esse where simplesmente você estará efetuando update em tudo mesmo.

Caso queira saber qual query exata que esta sendo gerada, você pode utilizar o seguinte comando:

```
print_r($this->db->last_query());
```